# Untar files in subdirectories while keeping them in the subdirectories

Tags: unix, scripting, tar

I am trying to recursively untar the contents of a whole lot of directories that have .tar files in them, but without creating any new subdirectories.

I am successfully able to do one at a time with this command

```
gtar -xf *.tar --strip-components 2
```

However, I have to BE IN the subdirectory in order for that to work, and I want to do it en masse from the directory above.

Here is my directory structure (except in reality I have hundreds):

```
/top_directory
   /sub1
      tarfile1.tar
   /sub2
      tarfile1.tar
   /sub3
      tarfile1.tar
   /sub4
      tarfile1.tar
```

So I can't just move them all up a directory and then untar them either, because they are all called tarfile1.tar, so they need to remain in their subdirectories.

However, I don't want them to create any MORE subdirectories; I just want the files that they contain, hence why I need to use --strip-components.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
/top_directory
       /sub1
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
          file3.txt
       /sub2
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
       /sub3
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
          file3.txt
       /sub4
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
```

I think I've gotten close with this command:

```
for file in *; do gtar -xf ${file} --strip-components 2; done
```

but it returns this error: `gtar: This does not look like a tar archive`

and when I try

```
for file in *.tar; do gtar -xf ${file} --strip-components 2; done
```

I get the same error.

How can I accomplish untarring all the files in the subdirectories, while keeping the untarred files IN those directories?

I'm on Solaris11.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm a little confused by your example commands.  You say you're doing one of the following:

```
for file in *; do gtar -xf ${file} --strip-components 2; done
```

or

```
for file in *.tar; do gtar -xf ${file} --strip-components 2; done
```

but neither of those seem to reflect your directory structure?  Like, why not `for file in */*.tar`?

Anyway, I created a tree that looks a bit like yours (within some top directory, I have `sub1` through `sub4`, each with a `tarfile1.tar` inside (i.e. `tree` shows the following):

```
.
├── sub1
│   └── tarfile1.tar
├── sub2
│   └── tarfile1.tar
├── sub3
│   └── tarfile1.tar
└── sub4
    └── tarfile1.tar

4 directories, 4 files
```

So, I then came up with this modification of your code:

```bash
for file in */*.tar; do
  (cd "`dirname "$file"`";
   gtar -xf "`basename "$file"`" --strip-components 2);
done
```

And that seemed to work for me, producing (more `tree` output):

```
.
├── sub1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── tarfile1.tar
├── sub2
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── tarfile1.tar
├── sub3
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── tarfile1.tar
└── sub4
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2.txt
    ├── file3.txt
    └── tarfile1.tar

4 directories, 16 files
```

The main things I did to get this were:

1. create a [subshell](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html), so I can `cd` to where the tar file is, without having to get back out later (because I get that for free when the subshell finishes);
2. Use `dirname` to get the directory name where the tarfile lives, which is what I then use to `cd`;
3. Use `basename` to get the filename of the tar file relative to the aforementioned directory name.

As a side note, I also added some double quotes (`"`) around various things just to set things up to be safe with filenames that might contain spaces or other characters that the shell might otherwise get tripped up by (a general good practice when dealing with data from outside the script, including filenames).

Hopefully this works for you, or can be adapted easily to do so.  Happy hacking!

Comment: Thank you lindes. When I try `for file in */*.tar` I get the same problem I've been having with other attempts I've made, which is that it's putting the sub-directories from within the .tar files into the top directory.  So the --strip-components flag isn't working, as it is creating the subdirectories, and it's also not putting them IN the subdirectories, it's putting them in the top directory, so this has 2 issues that aren't working for me.

Comment: Regarding your code above, when I tried it I got a "bad directory" error; this is most likely because my directory name is very long.  Is there a way to just use the current directory, rather than hardcoding the directory?  I'm not clear on why we're changing directories? I just want to run it recursively from the top directory, and for it to unzip all .tar files in all subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm.  This sounds like several problems, so I'm not entirely sure how to address this in this context.  A few thoughts and things to try, though:

1. if you try `for file in */*.tar; do echo "$file"; done`, does that give you the list of tar files that you expect?  (If not, what's missing that should be there, or present that shouldn't?)

2. I'm not sure what gives a "bad directory" error.  That's not an error I'm familiar with from UNIX/Linux land... how long is very long, and what platform are you on?

3. I'm changing directories so that the extract can happen where the tar file is...

Comment: 4. This is probably at a level of complexity where it's worth putting this in a file as a script that you can run -- even if it's only needed once, it'll just make it easier to tweak the details until you get things right.  Try breaking things down into pieces, and get each piece correct, and then glue them back together.  I trust you can get this.  And if I see more questions from you, I'll try to answer, but I'm not always on here, and I'm not sure what you're doing that's different from what the question describes (but obviously something, because "top_directory/sub1" isn't very long).